# i need to write the list of records from the list Row_Items in an excel sheet at column F (under Incident coumn)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

i am trying to read the data from the 'Row Labels'(A Coumn) and writing the data at Incident(F Column) 
[image]

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Procsslabel.Visible = true;
    Incident_Path = Incident_AnalysistextBox.Text.Trim();
    Excel.Application xlApp ;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
    Excel.Range range ;
    string str;
    int rCnt = 0;
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Incident_Path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item("Ageing");
    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
    for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
    {
       string  str1 = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        if(str1=="Row Labels")
        {
            for (rCnt = rCnt+1; rCnt < range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
            {
                str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                List<string> Row_Items = new List<string>();
                Row_Items.Add(str);//Adding items to this list
                MessageBox.Show(str);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    //string cellName;// Here i want write the data into my excel sheet under F column
    //int counter=1;
    //foreach (var item in Row_Items)// Here i am getting error that Row_Items does not exist in this context
    // {
    //cellName = "F" + counter.ToString();
    //range = sheet.get_Range(cellName, cellName);
    //range.Value2 = item.ToString();
    //++counter;
       //}

    xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
    xlApp.Quit();
    Procsslabel.Visible= false;
    MessageBox.Show("The Ageing Report has been successfully updated");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to write a formula to the F column that would copy the value from the cells in the A Column.